# Protect cell content, but allow row deletion with PHPSpreadSheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

How to prevent editing of cell content, but allow rows to be deleted.

Context: the spreadsheet is to be downloaded, updated and imported.  Where there may be many many rows, but only a couple of rows are needed to be imported.  The `customer_email` and `site_id` columns should be protected but the access can be updated to either `Yes` or `No` and the rows deleted to only import the required data.

Initial download:

```
customer_email  | site_id | access
alice@email.com | 1       | Yes
alice@email.com | 2       | No
alice@email.com | 3       | No
bob@email.com   | 1       | No
bob@email.com   | 2       | No
bob@email.com   | 3       | Yes
```

Rows deleted and `access` updated:

```
customer_email  | site_id | access
alice@email.com | 1       | No
bob@email.com   | 1       | No
```

There is a [recipe](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet) for protecting the sheet and a [full list of functions can be seen on github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/9fdcaabe3cfe49e736e8e92a6700a756776407df/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Protection.php) but I'm not getting what I want and I'm not sure it is possible.  The recipe states:

> Excel offers 3 levels of "protection":
>   
>   Document: allows you to set a password on a complete spreadsheet, allowing changes to be made only when that password is entered.
>   Worksheet: offers other security options: you can disallow inserting rows on a specific sheet, disallow sorting, ...
>   Cell: offers the option to lock/unlock a cell as well as show/hide the internal formula.

But is not clear as to whether it is possible to lock contents of cells while allowing rows to be deleted.  I have tried to do this with the following code but the delete option remains greyed out when right clicking a row.

After running `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` add `test.php`:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'some data');
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'other data');
$sheet->setCellValue('A3', 'more data');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()
    ->setSheet(true)
    ->setDeleteRows(true);

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('test_delete_rows.xlsx');
```

Can anyone please advise whether this is possible and if so, what am I missing in the above code to achieve this?

Comment: _But is not clear as to wether it is possible to lock contents of cells while allowing rows to be deleted._ Did you try it? Thats the best test

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I have tried it and included the code above, is something confusing about the code I've included?